# What else can be deduced from the following class grade summary information?

Tags: r, distributions, dataset

Lets say for example a class of students and their grades are the data set.
Lets say there are around 35 students.

Here is what you know:

```
Your mark
The class average
The median mark
The standard deviation
```

Are there any other conclusions about this data that can be made given this information?

Thanks

Comment: The most information usually hides in the data itself, not the description of it (-;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can probably also compute upper bounds on the number of students who did better or worse than you did. The population version would be via [Chebyshev's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality).

For example, if $X_{me}$ is 'my' score, $s^2$ is the sample variance, $\bar{X}$ is the sample mean, and $X_i$ are the class scores, including 'mine', we have
$$s^2 = \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i} (X_i - \bar{X})^2$$
Now partition the sum into parts which are more extreme than my score and those which are less extreme:
$$(n-1) s^2 = \sum_{i \in I} (X_i - \bar{X})^2 + \sum_{i \not\in I}(X_i - \bar{X})^2$$,
where $I$ is the set of indices $i$ such that $|X_i - \bar{X}| \ge |X_{me} - \bar{X}|$. Now bound the summands in the right sum by zero from below, and bound those in the left sum by the condition defining $I$:
$$(n-1) s^2 \ge \sum_{i \in I} (X_{me} - \bar{X})^2 + \sum_{i \not\in I}0 = |I| (X_{me} - \bar{X})^2$$
And thus you have
$$|I| \le (n-1)s^2 / (X_{me} - \bar{X})^2$$

Now $I$ includes all those in the class that did better than I did, if I beat the mean, and thus you have an upper bound on that number in that case.

Using the sample median and a sample version of [Gauss' Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_inequality), you may be able to prove a tighter bound, but with some more assumptions on the distribution, and the proof is not as clear.

(*n.b.* This is, I believe, essentially how Chebyshev's inequality is proved.)

Comment: How do I calculate this?

Comment: This looks like a homework question.  What are the rules about homework questions on SE?  I don't see anything in the FAQ -- but I would probably be more willing to contribute if you could convince me this is **not** homework. PS.  If you want to know how to calculate bounds using Chebyshev's inequality, just follow the link posted!  There is an example in the middle of that page ...

Comment: @Ben: visit http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=homework .  Note that most homework questions are both artificial and specific.  The vagueness of this one suggests to me it originates from a personal interest only.

Comment: Believe me, it is purely interest, not homework. But believe what you want.

Answer (score 4):

Since the data set is grades, you probably also know the minimum and maximum possible scores, e.g. 0 and 100.  Given the median and first two moments, you can fit a variety of models to the sample statistics, say a scaled beta distribution.  This would give you tighter estimates than Chebyshev's inequality, although you'd be making some serious regularity and smoothness assumptions.  (The nifty thing with a beta distribution is that the mean and variance completely define it, so you could use the median as a validation statistic.)  Sounds like fun!